# Python warnings treated as errors, cannot disable

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

I am having a bizarre problem with warnings in python. I am using a large code base with many modules and I can't create a small script that reproduces this problem, sorry there is no minimum example. Whenever there is a warning, the program treats it as an error and exits. This is not for a specific type of warning, it is seemingly for all of them (at least RuntimeWarning, PendingDeprecationWarning, and UserWarning). I cannot easily prevent the warnings, it would require extensive modification of someone else's work, and they aren't a problem for the functionality of the code.

Here are some things I have tried that did NOT work:

Command line flag -W

Checked to make sure $PYTHONWARNINGS was not getting set

Verified that sys.warnoptions was empty

Preface script with:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

I was already using logging, changed logging setup to:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

Are there any true python gurus out there who can help?

EDIT:

The culprit which I'm having trouble getting around is a divide by zero. The correct behavior should be returning a NaN (which will later get converted to zero). I have to use a numpy array divide for speed reasons, breaking this out into a loop is not viable. Here are two more things I tried, where arr2 contains zeros:

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore')
z = np.divide(arr1,arr2)
```

or

```
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    z = np.divide(arr1,arr2)
```

In both of these cases I STILL get a RuntimeWarning followed by the program exiting.

EDIT AGAIN:

I found the offending line of code, but I don't understand why it would cause this problem:

```
warnings.simplefilter("ignore",lineno=32)
```

If anyone can help explain this to me, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you could always try replacing zeros in the denominator array with NaNs, something like:

```
denom[denom == 0.0] = np.NaN #watch out for float equality here
numer / denom
```

Comment: This worked for getting around that one instance, thanks for the idea, but doesn't fix the overall problem. Now things are just breaking somewhere else...